# Nextjs 13 & react slick

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

Hi its mi first time using nextjs, when try use  [React-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/) get next error

If this package cannot be used in next, could you tell me some functional alternatives in nextjs to create this same type of carousel?

This is the error

```
error - node_modules\react-slick\lib\track.js (26:112) @ _inherits
error - TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:60:15)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:318:5)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:355:2)
    at (sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js (C:\Users\17864\Desktop\Nice Travel\nice_travel_app\my-project\.next\server\app\houses\page.js:668:1)   
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\17864\Desktop\Nice Travel\nice_travel_app\my-project\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/inner-slider.js:11:14)
    at (sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/inner-slider.js (C:\Users\17864\Desktop\Nice Travel\nice_travel_app\my-project\.next\server\app\houses\page.js:646:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\17864\Desktop\Nice Travel\nice_travel_app\my-project\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js:15:20)
    at (sc_server)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js (C:\Users\17864\Desktop\Nice Travel\nice_travel_app\my-project\.next\server\app\houses\page.js:657:1) {
  type: 'TypeError',
  page: '/houses'
}
null
```

this its my code on next app

layout.tsx

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

screen.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";

function MainPage() {

    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Slider {...settings}>
                <div>
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>3</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>4</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>5</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>6</h3>
                </div>
            </Slider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainPage;
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.14.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^0.1.10",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.1",
    "next": "13.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-slick": "0.25.2",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "standard": "^17.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

I'm follow all steps in crearte create app and works fine in next not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `'use client'` at the beginning of the component jsx/tsx file.

Also see here: [akiran/react-slick/#1347](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1347)